Laravel 9, hacer una instancia de una consulta
estoy intentando evitar la duplicación de código, tengo algunas consultas en mi controlador que requiero reutilizar en dos variables distintas, ya que hay un where que debo hacer para obtener data diferente para con los mismos filtros anteriores pero que me daria diferente data.
    public function totalesStatus(Request $request)
    {
        $facturas = Factura::selectRaw('ifnull(sum(facturas.cantidad - ifnull(notas_creditos.cantidad,0)),0) as total')
            ->leftJoin('notas_creditos', 'facturas.id', '=', 'notas_creditos.factura_id')
            ->whereNull('facturas.ingreso_id')
            ->whereYear('facturas.fechaDePago', '=', $validadData['year']);

        if ($request->has('month')) {
            $facturas->whereMonth('facturas.fechaDePago', '=', $validadData['month']);
        }
        if ($request->has('lineas_negocio_id') || $request->has('cliente_id')) {
            if ($request->has('lineas_negocio_id')) {
                $facturas->join('oc_factura', 'facturas.id', '=', 'oc_factura.factura_id')
                    ->join('oc_venta', 'oc_factura.oc_id', '=', 'oc_venta.oc_id')
                    ->join('cecos', function ($join) use ($validadData) {
                        $join->on('oc_venta.ceco_id', '=', 'cecos.id')
                            ->where('cecos.lineas_negocio_id', '=', $validadData['lineas_negocio_id']);
                    })->distinct();
            }
            if ($request->has('cliente_id')) {
                $facturas->where('facturas.cliente_id', '=', $validadData['cliente_id']);
            }
        }
        $status['pl'] =  $facturas->PorLiberar()->first()->total;
        $status['pp'] =  $facturas->liberado()->first()->total;
    }

Como pueden ver tengo estas consulta con los diferentes where lo que yo requiero hacer lo siguiente.
$pl = $facturas;
$pp = $facturas;

$status['pl'] =  $pl->where('facturas.liberado', 0)->first()->total;
$status['pp'] =  $pp->where('facturas.liberado', 1)->first()->total;

pero al hacerlo se modifica la consulta original como si fueran una misma consulta y no individuales

Pero basta con que anexes el where que los diferencia según un filtro entonces no ? Digamos, una validación, si viene un boolean true, hace el where A, y si viene un false, hace el where B. Según dices es la misma consulta, solo con esa diferencia de where.

Has intentado clonar la variable? Laravel esta basado en PHP por lo tanto podrías usar la funcionalidad de clonar variables, a continuación te pongo un ejemplo de como podría funcionarte:
$pl = clone $facturas;
$pp = clone $facturas;

$status['pl'] =  $pl->where('facturas.liberado', 0)->first()->total;
$status['pp'] =  $pp->where('facturas.liberado', 1)->first()->total;

Espero que esto pueda ayudarte a solucionar tu problema.
Saludos
